# Can the Olympus EPL3 camera be tethered to a computer?

Tags: tethering, olympus

I own an Olympus EPL3 camera, and I'm finding it hard to get a clear answer regarding tethering. Can I tether this camera to a computer for studio shots?

If needed, I'm happy to use 3rd party software.

Comment: What OS do you have? I don't think any of the major players (Lightroom, Aperture, Capture One) support Olympus, especially a 4/3, so you are probably looking at open source. There are a few around.

Comment: Hi,I have a Windows OS. I was really hoping to tether my computer to my new camera, I just assumed I would be able to. What a shame. Thanks heaps for your help answering this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported by Olympus and I know of no third-party software to control the E-PL3.

You can see the Live-View display on HDMI which means you can see what its doing but you cannot control the camera to take pictures.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm new to photography, and I'm trying to take some studio product picture for use on the web. My backgrounds are turning out grey, even though they look white on camera screen. I thought it would be helpful to view them directly onto the computer. I'll try the HDMI cord and see if I can view the pictures directly on the computer.

Comment: Set the camera to overexpose a little. Light meters are designed to try and make everything grey, so they will underexpose white and overexpose black. Sometimes you have to compensate for that.

Comment: @Nat - He means to apply some positive exposure compensation. A +2/3 or so usually does it but since you have an E-PL3, you can do better by using the *Spot Highlight* metering mode and pointing it to the white-background. This ensures it rendered as a highlight without losing any details.